# Retry Unhandled error in Deferred: in scrapy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scrapy, boto

I got `BotoServerError` in Scrapy when uploading images to AWS S3 because it happens to be a server down. How can I handle those errors so I can set the item pipeline to sleep for a while and retry uploading again?

```
2016-11-17 05:59:55 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\threadpool.py", line 246, in inContext
    result = inContext.theWork()
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\threadpool.py", line 262, in <lambda>
    inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 1426, in set_contents_from_string
    encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 1293, in set_contents_from_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 750, in send_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 951, in _send_file_internal
    query_args=query_args
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.py", line 668, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "D:\Kerja\HIT\PYTHON~1\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1028, in _mexe
    raise BotoServerError(response.status, response.reason, body)
BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Comment: I do not think Scrapy's S3 upload handler does retries. I'm not sure there's a simple fix other than migrating to boto3 (there's [an open issue for this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1866))

Comment: You can also try installing `botocore` (scrapy will use `botocore` instead of `boto` if it's available). It seems botocore does some retries (I can't find much detail about it though)

Comment: Thanks! `boto3` solves it!

Comment: This is probably because `boto3` depends on `botocore` so installing it installed `botocore` also. (Scrapy does not use `boto3`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @paul! Based on his answer, I solve it by uninstalling package `boto` and install package `boto3` instead.